# Using getElementById method to find an element inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I have an iframe:

```
<iframe id="CPHNavBar_TBDC081D1008_frameSticky" src="/stickyserviceavailabilitycheck"></iframe>
```

and I need to reference a piece of css code that lives on the src portion above. This code will select it when on the src page:

```
document.getElementById( "ContentPlaceHolder1_C001_btnSMBAddressCheckYes");
```

Is it possible to reference the css element from page with the

```
<iframe id="CPHNavBar_TBDC081D1008_frameSticky" src="/stickyserviceavailabilitycheck"></iframe>
```

hosted on it?

Comment: You cannot use JavaScript on a page loaded with a different domain.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), if two pages do not share a domain name and port number, one page cannot edit the DOM, or run JS on the other page. (Usually attempted via the `<iframe>` element). The same origin policy also applies to XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: The pages do share the same domain name though.